# How can I get compilation stats at a function level in webpack to identify files affected by changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

I need to find the files in my project that will suffer regression when i change a particular function in a particular file. I need to develop a webpack plugin for the same that helps me identifying the regression files.

I tried exploring the compilation stats of webpack, I was able to find which file has imported which other file directly or through some other file. Now i need to do it at the function level that which are the files in my project that are using any current function.

I need to develop a webpack plugin for the same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.